# How do I numerically integrate a string with variables in python?

Tags: python, scipy, eval, numerical-integration

Disclaimer: total noob here, please keep it as simple as possible

My plan was to use `scipy.integrate.quad()` and `eval()` (code inection won't be a problem in my case). This works fine when the only variable in the equation is the integration variable:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

equation = '1+2*x'

result = quad(lambda x: eval(equation), 0, 1)
```

Adding addtional variables works as long as they are defined:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

equation = 'A+B*x'
A=1
B=2

result = quad(lambda x: eval(equation), 0, 1)
```

However if i try to give `eval()` those additional variables with a dictionary like I'm supposed to, it suddenly starts complaining that it can't find x:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

equation = 'A+B*x'
paramsDict = {'A':1, 'B':2}

result = quad(lambda x: eval(equation, paramsDict), 0, 1)

>>> NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

So apparently `eval()` can return a function with an undefined variable no problem unless I give it *some* values to work with? How can I work around this?

Comment: I'm not sure how `'1+2x'` works, since `2x` is not proper python

Comment: Just a typo, edited

Comment: Even if you get this work, it doesn't sound like a good idea.  `quad` calls the function many times (21 min if I recall one test correctly).  Doing the `eval` many times will add to its inefficiency.   I think it would be smarter to have your user write the function `def` in a separate file, which you then import  Extra arguments can be passed via the `args` parameter.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I'll keep it in mind for the future should I run into performance issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), you'll see that the second parameter sets the scope of what the `eval` function can see, specifically it provides the set of globals that `eval` can utilize. Therefore, in your case it will lose access to `x`. This can be fixed in several ways, my quick and dirty solution is the following:

```py
result = quad(lambda x: eval(equation, {**paramsDict, 'x':x}), 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I tried adding 'x':x to paramsDict but somehow couldn't think of doing it while calling eval so that it actually works